# javascript in ajax response works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera BUT NOT internet explorer 11 - Object does not support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

I tried to find the answer for my question in the other posts, but unfortunately I couldn't find any, that solves the problem.

So, I am trying to request a jquery Datepicker via AJAX. I have uploaded the example here. You can check the working example in Firefox, Chrome or Opera:

[Ajax javascript example](http://developertest.net76.net/)

Unfortunately this does not work in internet explorer 11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>  

 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Json javascript example</h1>
    <button id="requestHtml" onclick="callAjax()">request new HTML</button>
    <div id="emptyDiv"></div>     
 </body>
</html>
```

The javascript code looks like this:

```
function callAjax()
{
    $.ajax({
            url: "/htmlJson.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache : false,
            type: 'post',
            data: '',
            error: function(){
                alert("Error in Ajax response");
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                $("#emptyDiv").html(response.htmlCode);
            }
    });
}
```

And finally the code in htmlJson.php:

```
<?php
$json = array(
    'success' => true,
    'htmlCode' => ""
);


$data = '
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="Birthdate" class="form-control" style="background-color:#ffffff; color:gray" value="Birthdate" readonly placeholder="Birth date" />
    </div>                         
    <script>
    $("#Birthdate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }); 
    </script>
';

$json['success'] = true;
$json['htmlCode'] = $data;

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

When I run this in firefox, chrome and opera it works perfectly and the datepicker shows up when clicking in the birthdate form. However in Internet explorer 11 it shows up the alert in eval code:

```
  Object does not support this property or method
```

I have read that one shouldn't mix html code and javascript code in the ajax response. However I have seen this working in other examples.

From other answers I have also tried to put the javascript code directly into the success callback function. Unfortunately the same behaviour. Worked in Firefox, Chrome and also Opera but not internet explorer 11. It showed again that the method is not supported by this element.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Cheers Stefan

---

**UPDATE**

I just found out that it runs smoothly in IE11 if I let it run locally on my XAMPP. Could this issue be related to some server settings?

Comment: Your example worked flawless for me. It had show a date picker and no errors in the console. What property exactly it said it does not support? More than that, in F12 Tools in Emulation and Document mode it is showing "Edge (Default)"?

Comment: Oh really? In internet explorer 11? I also used the developer tool and in the debugger it says that the object ($("#Birthdate")) does not support the method datepicker(). And yes the mode is set to "Edge (Default)". The Problem is not only datepicker. All other returned javascripts (which are loaded in the header) on my original page show the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to return mixed html+js code via ajax try wrapping js jQuery code into `jQuery.ready` event handler like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#Birthdate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }); 
});
```

**UPD**

Here is an updated version:

1) remove JS code from response /htmlJson.php

2) modify your scripts.js accordingly

```
 //code for scripts.js
function initDatePicker(){

  $("#Birthdate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        }); 
}

function callAjax()
{
    $.ajax({
            url: "/htmlJson.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache : false,
            type: 'post',
            data: '',
            error: function(){
                alert("Error in Ajax response");
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                $("#emptyDiv").html(response.htmlCode);
   initDatePicker();
            }
    });
}
```

**UPD2**

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   var initDatePicker = function(){
            $("#Birthdate").datepicker({
                  changeMonth: true,
                  changeYear: true,
                  timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
                  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
              }); 
        }


    var callAjax = function() {

        $.ajax({
                url: "htmlJson.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache : false,
                type: 'post',
                data: '',
                error: function(){
                    alert("Error in Ajax response");
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $("#emptyDiv").html(response.htmlCode);
                    initDatePicker();

                }
        });
    }

  });
```

Comment: Hm do you mean to put your code into the script tag within the htmlJson.php file? I just tried it, unfortunately still the same error. It works again in all other browsers but not IE 11. What would be the better approach? [/br] Seperating the HTML and javascript into different files?

Comment: check the upd version

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just tried it. Unfortunately still not working in IE11. I tried a slightly different approch before and put the javascript code directly beneath the line `$("#emptyDiv").html(response.htmlCode);` . Just didnt put it in a sub function. Unfortunately also not working :(

Comment: did you update code here - ***.net76.net/js/scripts.js ? I can't see it

Comment: the error emerges on $("#Birthdate").datepicker, so if you try to wrap all your scripts.js code in jQuery(document).ready(function($) { that should help

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! It works now on IE11, Windows Phone and also my Windows tablet :-)  However I had to make a slight modification. `function callAjax()` had to be changed to ` window.callAjax = function()` so that the button can access it. Could you update it so that other uses can find it? Thanks again!